# python matplotlib backend change after program parameters reading

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wrote a program and would like to give to the user the opportunity to run it either on compute with a graphical environment or not.

Currently through hard coding it I can do either one or the other by changing the matplotlib import at the top of my program file, before importing `pyplot`.

with graphical environment

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Qt4Agg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
...
```

without graphical environment

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("agg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
...
```

the remaining code would look something like that:

```
...
import os, sys, argparse

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--noX", action="store_true", dest="noX")
    params = parser.parse_args()

    data = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(data)
    if not params.noX:
        plt.show()
    plt.savefig("foo.png")

    sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Is it possible to change the backend based on the `noX` parameter value?

Comment: Ok I have thought about a possible solution. import sys; import matplotlib; matplotlib.use("agg")  if "--noX" in sys.argv else matplotlib.use("Qt4Agg"); import matplotlib.pyplot as plt. I will try that

Answer (score 1):

You can set the backend o a condition:

```
import matplotlib
if not params.noX:
    matplotlib.use("agg")
else:
    matplotlib.use("Qt4Agg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

If you only plot inside `main`, move your import inside this function:

```
import argparse


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--noX", action="store_true", dest="noX", default=False)
    params = parser.parse_args()

    import matplotlib
    if not params.noX:
        matplotlib.use("agg")
    else:
        matplotlib.use("Qt4Agg")
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    data = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(data)
    if not params.noX:
        plt.show()
    plt.savefig("foo.png")

    sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If you want to do plotting everywhere, use special function to parse the
command line arguments and call it only once.

```
import argparse


def _parse_cmd_args():
    """Parse command line args.
    """
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--noX", action="store_true", dest="noX", default=False)
    params = parser.parse_args()
    return params


PARAMS = _parse_cmd_args()
# Want to prevent any further call to `_parse_cmd_args()`?
# Un-comment the following line:
# del _parse_cmd_args


import matplotlib
if not PARAMS.noX:
    matplotlib.use("agg")
else:
    matplotlib.use("Qt4Agg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def main():
    data = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(data)
    if not PARAMS.noX:
        plt.show()
    plt.savefig("foo.png")
    sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I was thinking about something like that. The problem is if make a call to plt outside the main() function. Can I make the import "global"?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try? As a general rule you can't change the backend. So you will have to pospone the decision until you know the value of `noX`. Keep in mind that you can `import` at any time and any place. It is adviced to `import` at the beginning of the file but that's not always possible.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so combining the idea of Mike with the global import of plt I come up with something like that to do the trick. Sorry for bothering you, it was actually simpler than first envisaged.

```
import os, sys, argparse

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("agg") if "--noX" in sys.argv else matplotlib.use("Qt4Agg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--noX", action="store_true", dest="noX", default=False)
    params = parser.parse_args()

    data = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(data)
    if not params.noX:
        plt.show()
    plt.savefig("foo.png")

    sys.exit(0)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```